# Get bootstrap datepicker running in clojurescript

Tags: clojurescript, bootstrap-datepicker

I am trying to run the bootstrap datepicker: http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/ in clojurescript, but always get an "undefined function" error when executing this code:

```
(let [elem (sel1 :#dateid)]
  (.datepicker elem))
```

I use dommy for selection of the dom element.

I setup a smallest not working example here: https://github.com/sveri/cljs-datepicker
You can check it out and start it with: lein ring server and lein cljsbuild auto, then go to: localhost:3000

The answer is most probably pretty simple, but I just dont get it working. Any help is appreciated.

Best Regards,
Sven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use $ jquery function and string selector:

```
(let [elem (js/$ "#dateid")]
  (.datepicker elem))
```

Comment: Ok, that works, but why does the dommy selection not work? Does dommy not return the same as the jquery selector?

Comment: no, dommy will return you dom HTMLElement, jquery's $ returns some JS object that wraps element. datepicker functions defined for jquery wrapper.